# How to Sorting Nested List<dynamic> by one of its variable Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to sort a List by one of its value; I want to sort it by the 'name' alphabetically.

```
List<dynamic> list = [
    {
        'name':'abc',
        'other imformations':'-',
    },
    {
        'name':'abc',
        'other imformations':'-',
    }
]
```

I have tried (copied from another post):

```
list.sort((a, b) {
    var x = a['name'].compareTo(b['name']);
    if (x != 0)
        return x;
    return a['name'].compareTo(b['name']);
});
```

I have also tried:

```
    list.sort(
            (a, b) => a['name'].toString().toLowerCase().compareTo(
                    b['name'].toString().toLowerCase(),
            ),
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to print list that is sorted by name, then can use this code below:

```
print(list..sort((a, b) => a['name'].compareTo(b['name'])));
```